# Как отследить кик бота из чата?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Я храню ID чатов в базе данных Sqlite3, мне нужно, чтобы если администратор чата исключил бота, то бот удалит ID этого чата из БД.

Как это реализовать?
Пробовал через декоратор @on_chat_member_updated, не вышло.